# How to change the position of the whole text (title, headers and body) in reveal.js to top left?

Tags: html, css, r, markdown, reveal.js

I have a presentation using reveal.js and the text (title, body, etc.) change position every time I change slide.

Is there a way to fix text and title to be top left (so that at least the title stays in place?)

In the following image, you can see that the title is shifting down from one slide to the next (use the search box" as a reference).

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you have your YAML header setup incorrectly if you are not getting the expected behaviour.

```
---
output:
  revealjs::revealjs_presentation:
    center: true
---
```

The `center: true` entry is for vertical positioning according to the *reveal.js* configuration ([link](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js#configuration)).

> // Vertical centering of slides
>   center: true

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know that this was actually controlling all of the text. This make more sense!

Comment: but what if i want the title to be a give cm  below the top og the page. How do i set this?